# Install usbutils packages after create image in Yocto

Tags: package-management, raspberry-pi, yocto

I created a image Linux using Yocto porting a small version Linux to my Raspberry Pi.

I just did this to learn how compile a Linux/Kernel to embedded system.

But, I need some packages in my system. How do I install the usbutils packages?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include usbutils in your local.conf. To do this add the following line to build/conf/local.conf

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " usbutils "
```

Now you can either rebuild the image completely by wiping the bitbake tmp folder (NOT /tmp) and running

```
bitbake *insertImageName*
```

If you just want to build the RPM and to install it afterwards you can run

```
bitbake usbutils
```

And then copy over the rpm from 
    tmp/deploy/rpm/*architecture*/usbutils-*version*.rpm

In my case my architecture is corei7_64, so my path is

```
tmp/deploy/rpm/corei7_64/usbutils-008-r0.1.corei7_64.rpm
```

If you need any more help, let me know.